# How do I turn an NLA Material node animation back to keyframes?

Tags: animation, materials, actions

I fiddled around with the NLA with an Material node with keyframes in NLA and made then into actions, but now I want to convert it back to keyframes but there's no tutorial (at least none for material node actions) So how do I turn it back?

---

[image]

Comment: So I guess you can't and you need to duplicate the keyframes instead

Comment: How do I do that? Can't seem to do anything much

https://imgur.com/a/a9Na9mD

Comment: If you press Tab it will reload the action in the Dope Sheet, switch it to Action Editor, create a new action and duplicate your keyframes?

Comment: Nothing comes up

Comment: You probably need to have both the object and the node selected, and open the Dope Sheet of course

Comment: Done all that, nothing is in the summary other then transformations in action editor, but it appears in normal dope sheet

(edit, it's appearing in timeline now and I think I got it)